# Trigger callback when deleting an associated has_and_belongs_to_many record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We're trying the capture when a cleaner gets removed from a job but none of the callbacks we have tried (`after_save` and `after_commit`) get triggered.

I suspect that the method `Job#release!` triggers a database query without involving Active Record.

How can trigger the `create_vacant_availabilities` callback after a cleaner gets removed from a job?

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :cleaners, through: :assignments

  after_save :create_vacant_availabilities
  def create_vacant_availabilities
    debugger # doesn't get triggered when calling release!
  end

  def release!(cleaner = nil)
    if cleaner
      self.cleaners.delete(cleaner)
    else
      self.cleaners = []
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `Assignment` is created or destroyed, it does not change the `Job` that it's paired with.

There are two options you could pursue.

First you can use `touch: true`. [From the Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)...

> **:touch**
>
> If true, the associated object will be touched (the updated_at/on attributes set to current time) when this record is either saved or destroyed. If you specify a symbol, that attribute will be updated with the current time in addition to the updated_at/on attribute.

...which means you would want something like

```
class Assignments
  belongs_to :job, touch: true
```

Note that this will not trigger `after_save` on the `Job`, so you will need to make it [an `after_touch` callback](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch).

The other possibility is [a `before_destroy` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) on the `Assignment`.

```
class Assignment
  belongs_to :job
  before_destroy :create_vacant_abilities_on_job

  def create_vacant_abilities_on_job
    self.job.create_vacant_abilities
  end
```

Depending on the logic behind `create_vacant_abilities`, you may want this to be an `around_destroy` or `after_destroy` callback.